# Error: Expected constructor, destructor, type conversion before '<' token

Tags: c++, function, boost, vector, matrix

the code is

```
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iterator>
#include <queue>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <cassert>
#include <cmath>
#include <iomanip>
#include <new>
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

using std::vector;

    #include <boost/numeric/ublas/matrix.hpp>
    #include <boost/numeric/ublas/io.hpp>
    #include <boost/numeric/ublas/operation.hpp>
#include <boost/numeric/ublas/vector.hpp>

    using namespace boost::numeric::ublas;

    boost::numeric::ublas::matrix<double> A_MATRIX(A_MATRIX_ROWS,A_MATRIX_COLUMNS);
    boost::numeric::ublas::matrix<double> Y_MATRIX(A_MATRIX_ROWS,1);


    vector <double> GPSR_BB(boost::numeric::ublas::matrix<double> &f_Y_MATRIX,boost::numeric::ublas::matrix<double> &f_A_MATRIX,int f_tau,int f_tolA){

vector<double> objective(2);

//sth inside function

return objective;

    }

    int main(){
        vector<double> objectives(maxiter+2);
        objectives=GPSR_BB(Y_MATRIX,A_MATRIX,tau,tolA);
        return 0;
    }
```

in line

```
vector <double> GPSR_BB(boost::numeric::ublas::matrix<double> &f_Y_MATRIX,boost::numeric::ublas::matrix<double> &f_A_MATRIX,int f_tau,int f_tolA){
```

I receive error

```
error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before ‘<’ token function
```

I guess, the problem is because of matrix data type, from boost library, which I have to pass to function, I don't think there is another way I can do for my specific problem.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you

Comment: One possible issue is that you pull in namespaces `std` and `boost::numeric::ublas`, both of which have a `vector`. Also, since you already pulled in the namespaces, why do you still write down the full type name of the matrix class? Also, your code is so damn hard to read. Why so many includes?

Answer (score 1):

boost::numeric::ublas has vector as well as namespace std. Try removing using namespace std and using the appropriate namespace to refer to the correct type.

Answer (score 0):

Try without a space between `vector` and `<double>`

```
vector<double> GPSR_BB
```